# using delete is crashing my program

Tags: c++

When I try to delete my pointers on distractor, my program is crashing, why?
I don't understand what I am doing wrong in my code.

Am I using new wrong?

class Matrix:

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    double **_array;
    int _rows, _cols;
...

  Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        if (rows <= 0 || cols <= 0)
            exit(-1);

        this->_array = new double*[rows];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            this->_array[i] = new double[cols];

        this->_rows = rows;
        this->_cols = cols;
    }
```

The problem is here:

```
   void Matrix::pow(int power, Matrix& result)
{
    /*if (result == NULL)
        exit(-1);*/

    if (result._cols != this->_cols || result._rows != this->_rows)
        exit(-1);

    // Can't pow the matrix, return mat of '0' values
    if (this->_cols != this->_rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < result._rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < result._cols; j++)
                result.setElement(i, j, 0);

        return;
    }

    /*if (power == 0)
        result = 1;*/

    double sum = 0;
    Matrix temp(this->_rows, this->_cols);

    // Copy this matrix to result matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < this->_rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < this->_cols; j++)
            result.setElement(i, j, this->_array[i][j]);

    // Pow loop
    for (int p = 1; p < power; p++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->_rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < this->_cols; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < this->_rows; k++)
                    sum += this->getElement(i, k) * result.getElement(k, j);

                temp.setElement(i ,j ,sum);
                sum = 0;
            }

        // Copy temp array to result array
        for (int i = 0; i < this->_rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < this->_cols; j++)
                result.setElement(i, j, temp.getElement(i, j));

        for (int i = temp._rows; i >= 0; i--)
            delete[] temp._array[i];

        delete[] temp._array;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
    void main()
    {
        int rows = 3, cols = 3;

        Matrix m1(rows, cols);
        Matrix other(rows, cols);
        Matrix result(rows, cols);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                m1.setElement(i, j, i + j);
                other.setElement(i, j, 3 * (i + j + 1));
            }
   m1.pow(3, result);
    }
```

SetElements:

```
void Matrix::setElement(int i, int j, double data)
{
    if (i < 0 || j < 0)
        exit(-1);

    if (i >= this->_rows || j >= this->_cols)
        exit(-1);

    _array[i][j] = data;
}
```

thanks

Comment: On a different note, none of those `this->`s is needed. The compiler knows that the code is dealing with members.

Comment: The code snippet doesn't include the `setElement` member function. Chances are that that's where the problem is. As others have said, the code should use `delete[]` and not `delete`, but for scalar types `delete` usually works okay.

Comment: Also, calling `exit()` in the middle of class code is not a habit to get into.

Comment: And while we're picking on the call to `exit()`, the argument for failure should be `EXIT_FAILURE`, not `-1`. The runtime library provides an appropriate value for the target system; `-1` may or may not mean anything to the target system.

Comment: [reopened] - it's not clear without seeing `setElement` that `delete[]` vs. `delete` is the actual problem here. `delete` may, indeed, be a distractor.

Comment: @PeteBecker I update my code and upload the setElement code.
also try to use delete[], also crash.

Comment: In the code here, assuming `delete` has been changed to `delete[]` in two places, there's no reason for a crash. So the code you're testing must be different from what you're showing.

Comment: @zcbd No issue here: http://ideone.com/P2p86M

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was update my topic, find the problem in function "pow" please take a look

Comment: Sigh. Is `temp` a `Matrix`? If so, don't delete its parts. The destructor will do that, and doing it twice is Really Bad.

Answer (score 0):

1)   The word for member function that prepares an object to no longer exist is destructor, not distractor.

2)   If you the array form of operator `new`, using the non-array form of operator `delete` - which you are - gives undefined behaviour.   Use the array form of operator `delete` instead.

3)   Your code, as shown, uses other functions that you have no provided.   Any of those, if implemented incorrectly, could be doing an invalid operation on a pointer, and therefore be OTHER causes of your crash.

4)   Don't bother to use dynamic memory allocation (operator `new`, etc) to work with dynamically allocated arrays.   You have demonstrated that doing so is error prone.  If you want a dynamically allocated array of `double` use a `std::vector<double>`.   If you want a two dimensional array of `double`, use a `std::vector<std::vector<double> >`.    Apart from being less error prone, a `std::vector` releases its memory correctly (as long as you don't write some other code which trashes memory).

Answer (score 0):

In your `Matrix`,  you allocate new arrays:

```
  ...
  this->_array = new double*[rows];          // <== array of pointers

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        this->_array[i] = new double[cols];  // <== arrays of doubles
  ...
```

But in your destructor you delete elements.  You have to correct this:   Everytime you alocate an array (`new []`),  you have to [delete the array](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-array-built-ins) (`delete []`), or you'll get undefined behaviour (for example crash):

```
for (int i = 0; i < _rows; i++)
    delete[] _array[i];   // <== delete array,  not element!! 

delete[] _array;  // <== delete array,  not element!!
```

***Note:** that everytime you're tempted to use new/delete, you should ask yourself, if it wouldn't be worth to consider using vectors instead.  It's very easy as this [online demo](http://ideone.com/s04zRu) show with your code reworked*

### Edit: your problem with `pow()`:

Here you create the matrix object `temp`:

```
Matrix temp(this->_rows, this->_cols);
```

This object will be destructed automatically at the end of the function `pow()`.  THis means that its destructor will call all the necessary `delete[]`.

The problem is that at the end of the function,  you manually do the job of the destructor,  so you `delete[]` temp's arrays.  Then the destructor tries to delete already deleted objects.  This is undefined behaviour and hence the crash !

All you have to do is get rid of the 3 last lines of `pow()` and the  unnecessary `delete[]` they contain.

Comment: I was change it like you said and I still get the crash problem

Comment: find the problem in another place in my code.. sorry for that.
adding it to top of topic

Comment: ok ! Good news.  I was about to propose you to slightly change your Matrix to use a vector, which would have revealed such issues (see edited note).

Comment: Ok !  No problem ;-)  Nothing to do with your problem, but if you're interesed, you could consier replacing the ugly exit(-1) with [proper exceptions](http://ideone.com/IuOcQz).

Comment: why there is nothing to do with my problem? 
do you take a look to the updated topic? 
and thanks for all your help !

Comment: Ok !  How do you initialise temp in the pow functioncode ?

Comment: Matrix temp(this->_rows, this->_cols);

Comment: Is result passed by reference or by value ?  Maybe you could provide the full definition of the function.

Comment: Ok !  Now it's clear !  Please have a look at my edit:  it should solve definitively your problem.